# Prevent from displaying the default CSRF error page in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, csrf

I don't like how CI behaves by default when a CSRF token has expired. For instance, when a  user has displayed the login form for a long time and they finally submit it, this ugly blank page with the error message comes up.

I asked for ways to get around this, and someone told me to extend the **Security** class, and override its **csrf_show_error()** method, like this:

```
class MY_Security extends CI_Security {


    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

    }

    public function csrf_show_error()
    {
        // comment out the default action
        // show_error('The action you have requested is not allowed.');

        // add redirect actions here
        // I'd like to use some helper function here like redirect()

    }

}
```

The problem is that I can't, or I don't know how to get access to the libraries and helpers from here, in order to perform a redirect. I can't use the **get_instance()** function here because I get an error. So, what else couls I do? Or is there any other better option to prevent from showing this error page?

Comment: If you cant access the helper functions within the class to do a redirect then you can always just do what the helper function does by setting a `header()` redirect and setting the proper HTTP status code etc..

Comment: That's right cryptic. This is my last card to play. But it would be better to use code which is already implemented. A simple **redirect(current_url())** would be great. But I'd like to avoid hardcoding the inclusion of the URL helper within my custom class too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Core classes like `CI_Security` are instantiated before helpers and libraries - there is no ability to utilize these functions like you would elsewhere in a CI app.

You'll have to duplicate the functionality in the class using native PHP functions like `header()` which is not much of a hardship if you'd simply like to redirect to a prettier error page.

Comment: `header('Location: ' . htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));` to refresh the page with the sanitized URI.

Answer (score 3):

One of a way to do is extend `Security` class to redirect to the same page.

CodeIgniter User Guide - [Extending Core Class](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html)

Nice explanation of [How to handle an expired CSRF token after a page is left open](http://www.johnkieken.com/how-to-handle-an-expired-csrf-token-after-a-page-is-left-open/)

Answer (score 2):

For those who want change the page view, you can edit the file `error_general.php` in `/application/errors/error_general.php`. CodeIgniter uses that file to show general errors, like CSRF Errors.

Regards :).

Comment: Good to know but not really helpful if your site is using templates and views, as `error_general.php` is a complete page.