# Codeigniter CSRF token expired proper message and redirect

Tags: codeigniter-3

Codeigniter, CSRF token expired shows following error message :

```
The action you have requested is not allowed.
```

How to override this and redirect with flash message instead of intermediate page.

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14406922/prevent-from-displaying-the-default-csrf-error-page-in-codeigniter